# VS2010 - What is this little blue circle at the single-step yellow arrow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

[image]

When this blue circle appears, the execution doesn't follow the normal flow. The program may jump to random position of current function.

Comment: Are you perhaps stepping through optimised code? Or multithreaded code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means you're following multithreaded operations. The arrow jumps around to follow each thread's activities as they execute in parallel.